# Compare dates in two columns

Tags: excel-formula

I need to compare the dates in two columns of a spreadsheet to see if one date is 2 days greater than the other date.  For example, does the date in column H2 = the date in column A2 + 2 days?  What is the formula for such a comparison?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only working with dates, then using a difference will give you days, which you can use in your comparison.

[image]

For example, you may condition in the following way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, a visual indication may be adequate or even be more appropriate, for which Conditional Formatting is well suited:

Say select columns A and H, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., Use a formua to determine which cells to format, Format values where this formula is true:

```
=$A1+2=$H1
```

Format..., select to suit, OK, OK.